# Problems after installing the “New Hardware Support is Available”

Tags: hardware-enablement-stack

Problem started July 11th 2014 when I got the update. Each time when booting up my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I got a black screen with this message "Could not write Bytes: Broken Pipe" on the top Left hand corner. Today I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and now when I click on Software updater I see “New Hardware Support is Available”. Do I really need to get this update? Is there a way to avoid it? My PC is working fine without that update...

Answer (score 0):

Warning to you.  I accepted the hardware firmware update and thereafter it killed my wifi.  It removed my wifi driver and did not replace it.  I have since been able to restore my wifi (search on "hardware firmware" to find my problem titled "Latest hardware firmware update kills wifi" to see my solution). I suspect the firmware update is not really necessary.

Comment: See another Ask! question titled "Update Manager message 'new hardware support is available'".